# How to copy text in a box using js and html

Tags: javascript, html

I used the common way of copying text in a box it worked perfectly, but my main problem is that the value of my text is a certain parameters my website calls. When I input it into the text box, some part are cut of and I don't know why. Please help me out.

Here's the code :

```js
function myFunction() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
<input type="text" value="{{ $mailData["code"] }}" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

Comment: You realise both your fields have the same id, right? Id's should be unique. Did you want to copy the text of _both_ fields?

Comment: or is the problem you only see `{{ $mailData[` in the second field?

Answer (score 1):

change the one of " to ' in value of second input and unique your id

```js
function myFunction() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput2");
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput1">
<input type="text" value='{{ $mailData["code"] }}' id="myInput2">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had the same id for both inputs, they need to be different. Please refer to the following code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
    var copyText1 = document.getElementById("myInput1");
    copyText.select();
    copyText1.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value + " " + copyText1.value);
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
<input type="text" value="{{ $mailData['code'] }}" id="myInput1">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the " when you call `$mailData["code"]`, use ' instead. Also, as some else pointed out, ids should be unique. This example fixes both of your issues.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput1");
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput1">
<input type="text" value="{{ $mailData['code'] }}" id="myInput2">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

Comment: My website parameters specifies " only.